# I how to add multiple users to manytomanyFiled at ones

Tags: django

in `book.who_can_see.add(author.id, [2, 3])`
 payload["description"] return an array like [1,2]
so it seems i should convert the array to pure numbers with commas like 2,3 but I have no idea how.

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_book(request):
    print({"request.data": request.data})
    payload = request.data
    user = request.user
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(id=payload["author"])
        book = Book.objects.create(
            title=payload["title"],
            description=payload["description"],
            added_by=user,
            author=author,
        )
        #  payload["description"] this return an array like [1,2]
        # book.who_can_see.add(author.id, 2, 3)
        book.who_can_see.add(author.id, [2, 3])
        # it seems i should convert the array to pure numbers with commas like 2,3

        book.who_can_see.add(author.id)
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return JsonResponse({'books': serializer.data}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Something terrible went wrong'}, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of an asterisk (`*`) to unpack an iterable in function parameters:

```
#                      asterisk ↓
book.who_can_see.add(author.id, *[2, 3])
```